# How to add grid in magento admin form

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, adminform

[image: Need to added grid at highlighted place.]

How i can add customer grid at highlighted place ?

Comment: this option is not available in magento by default .You need to create your own form field to render customer grid at highlighted place. you can place customer grid in separate tab easily

Comment: Can we do this using custom type ?

Comment: i have never tried that. but yes we can

Comment: Okay i will check

Answer (score 5):

We can display grid in admin form using custom field type

[image: Magento admin form with grid]

> Form.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_ModuelName_Block_Adminhtml_Payment_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {
    protected function _prepareForm() {
        if (Mage::registry('data')) {
            $data = Mage::registry('data')->getData();
        } else {
            $data = array();
        }

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('wallpetpayment_walletpayment', array('legend' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Wallet Payment')));

        $fieldset->addType('customer_grid', 'Namespace_ModuelName_Block_Adminhtml_Payment_Edit_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Customergrid');

        $fieldset->addField('user_id', 'customer_grid', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Name'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'user_id',
            'onclick' => "",
            'onchange' => "",
            'disabled' => false,
            'readonly' => false,
            'tabindex' => 1
        ));



        $fieldset->addField('amount', 'text', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Amount'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
            'name' => 'amount',
        ));

        $wysiwygConfig = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig();
        $wysiwygConfig->addData(array('add_variables' => false,
            'add_widgets' => true,
            'add_images' => true,
            'directives_url' => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg/directive'),
            'directives_url_quoted' => preg_quote(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg/directive')),
            'widget_window_url' => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/widget/index'),
            'files_browser_window_url' => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg_images/index'),
            'files_browser_window_width' => (int) Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/cms/browser/window_width'),
            'files_browser_window_height' => (int) Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/cms/browser/window_height')
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('comment', 'editor', array(
            'name' => 'comment',
            'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Remarks'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Remarks'),
            'style' => 'width:800px; height:500px;',
            'config' => $wysiwygConfig,
            'required' => true,
            'wysiwyg' => true
        ));


        $form->setValues($data);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

> Now create
>   Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Payment\Edit\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Customergrid.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_ModuelName_Block_Adminhtml_Payment_Edit_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Customergrid extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract{
    protected $_element;

    public function getElementHtml()
    {
        return Mage::helper('core')->getLayout()->createBlock('blockname_node/adminhtml_payment_edit_form_renderer_fieldset_customer_grid')->toHtml();
    }
}
```

> Then Create
>   Namespace\ModuelName\Block\Adminhtml\Payment\Edit\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Customer\Grid.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_ModuelName_Block_Adminhtml_Payment_Edit_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('customerGrid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');


        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('user_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__(''),
            'index'     => 'entity_id',
            'type' => 'radio',
            'html_name' => 'user_id',
            'align'     => 'center',
            'filter' => false
        ));

        $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'entity_id',
            'type'  => 'number',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Name'),
            'index'     => 'name'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('email', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'email'
        ));



        $this->addColumn('Telephone', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Telephone'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'index'     => 'billing_telephone'
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('adminhtml/paymenthistory/customergrid', array('_current'=> true));
    }
}
```