# how to set Product grid at admin side form in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i set a product grid as like following pic. I try many time using magento functionality can any help me?

[image]

Comment: This is called Grid Serialize. Share the code what you have tried.

Comment: hi @userpk i tried this link.. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113497/how-to-add-grid-in-magento-admin-form#comment154229_113497. can you please give me a grid serialize best example.

Comment: the solution in http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-grid-serializer-admin-tabs-grid/