# How to add grid in fieldset magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, grid

I've a grid view already done, but I need to put it into a fieldset, how can I implement this?

This is my Grid.php

```
class Ns_Thorleif_Block_Adminhtml_Commerciaux_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('commerciaux_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    public function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('thorleif/commerciaux')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    public function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('id',
            array(
                'header' => 'ID',
                'align' => 'left',
                'width' => '10%',
                'index' => 'id'
            )
        );
        $this->addColumn('name',
            array(
                'header' => 'Category Name',
                'align' => 'left',
                'index' => 'name'
            )
        );
        $this->addColumn('route',
            array(
                'header' => 'Route',
                'align' => 'left',
                'index' => 'route'
            )
        );
        $this->addColumn('cat2',
            array(
                'header' => 'Category2',
                'align' => 'left',
                'index' => 'category2'
            )
        );
        $this->addColumn('tax',
            array(
                'header' => 'Tax',
                'align' => 'left',
                'index' => 'tax'
            )
        );
        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header' => 'Action',
                'align' => 'left',
                'index' => 'action'
            )
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

Doing some test to have a forms a put this code in the same file without grid

```
class Ns_Thorleif_Block_Adminhtml_Commerciaux_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);

    // section one
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('commerciaux_form', array('legend' => 'Configuration account'));

    $fieldset->addField('country', 'select', array(
        'label' => 'Country',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'values' => array('1' => 'Mexico','2' => 'Colombia', '3' => 'Argentina', '4' => 'Peru', '5' => 'Ecuador', '6' => 'Panama', '7' => 'Chile', '8' => 'Venezuela' ),
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'country'
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('email', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Email address',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'email'
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('key', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Api key',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'key'
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('tax', 'select', array(
        'label' => 'Tax',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'tax'
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('time', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Supply time',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'time'
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('warranty', 'textarea', array(
        'label' => 'Warranty',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'warranty'
    ));

    // section two
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('commerciaux_form_2', array('legend' => 'Variations Mapping'));

    $fieldset->addField('variation', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'You should match size if you want to upload products to Fashion subcategory',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'variation'
    ));

    // section three
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('commerciaux_form_3', array('legend' => 'Category Mapping'));
    $fieldset->addField('category', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Category',
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'category'
    ));


    if ($commerciauxData = Mage::registry('commerciaux_data')) {
        $form->setValues($commerciauxData->getData());
    }
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
}
```

so the idea I want to implement it having those forms ( two fieldset) and in the same page in third fieldset the grid.
[image]

Comment: please provide more information with your code.

Comment: form is working properly at your end??

Comment: you want three tabs on from page?

Comment: @Gopal, yes I've added a picture to have an idea regarding my request I want to implement. I'm new in magento so I'm trying to understand the relation and level between each folder(Model, Helper, Controller, Block).

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113497/how-to-add-grid-in-magento-admin-form?answertab=votes#tab-top) help to implement it. you have to create a new custom field type and render the grid on it.